# Visual Web Developer Session problem on debugging

Tags: c#, debugging, session

May I know is there any option or setting to maintain the Session variable of C# web application everytime I changed code and "Start Debugging" the web application?

I tend to lose all the Session and I need to relogin everytime in order to recreate the session and get the "member/admin area" working. This has slowed down my progress heavily :(